# Using primitive types with ClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader, primitive-types

I've got a piece of code that is used to turn string representations delivered by `Class.getCanonicalName()` into their corresponding instances of `Class`. This usually can be done using `ClassLoader.loadClass("className")`. However, it fails on primitive types throwing a `ClassNotFoundException`. The only solution I came across was something like this:

```
private Class<?> stringToClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if("int".equals(className)) {
        return int.class;
    } else if("short".equals(className)) {
        return short.class;
    } else if("long".equals(className)) {
        return long.class;
    } else if("float".equals(className)) {
        return float.class;
    } else if("double".equals(className)) {
        return double.class;
    } else if("boolean".equals(className)) {
        return boolean.class;
    }
    return ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(className);
}
```

That seems *very* nasty to me, so is there any clean approach for this?

Comment: If you're in Java 7, you might try a `switch` on the string.

Comment: Ouh, that's nice to know. However, the point is that I dont't want to check for certain types using String.equals. That's the nasty part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have an exception for this: `Class.forName(int.class.getName())`, I would say this is the way to go.

Checking Spring framework code http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html class, method `resolvePrimitiveClassName` , you will see that they do the same thing, but with a map ;). Source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.core/3.1.0/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.java#ClassUtils.resolvePrimitiveClassName%28java.lang.String%29

Something like this:

```
private static final Map primitiveTypeNameMap = new HashMap(16);
// and populate like this
primitiveTypeNames.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Class[] {
        boolean[].class, byte[].class, char[].class, double[].class,
        float[].class, int[].class, long[].class, short[].class}));
for (Iterator it = primitiveTypeNames.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Class primitiveClass = (Class) it.next();
    primitiveTypeNameMap.put(primitiveClass.getName(), primitiveClass);
}
```

Comment: Yes, `Class.forName("int")` would search for a class `int` in the default package (says the javadoc). A deficit in the java design.

Comment: Meh.  Primitive "classes" are inevitably going to be a dirty hack.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make life more fun, you'll also have trouble with arrays. This gets around the array problem:

```
private Pattern arrayPattern = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\.]*)\\[\\]");

public Class<?> getClassFor(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Matcher m = arrayPattern.matcher(className);
    if(m.find()) {
        String elementName = m.group(1);
        return Class.forName("[L" + elementName + ";"); // see below
    }
    return Class.forName(className);
}
```

The wrapping of the class name in [L(classname); - that I sourced [here](http://java.dzone.com/news/obtaining-array-class-java-ref). I can't see a cleaner way of doing it, but I'm sure there must be one.

Of course an array of primitive types will need a further set of special-case logic...